# Dovid's birth and death date

Tags: sources-mekorot, king-david

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shavuot)  states that King David, Ruth's descendant, was born and died on Shavuos. The source they brought was a Yerushalmi in Chagigah (2:3). I looked in the Yerushalmi and found nothing.

Does anyone know any other source that has this information

Comment: So far, I have found a mention http://breslovcenter.blogspot.com/2010/05/shavuos-and-dovid-hamelech.html and a mention with some sort of source -- Sharei Teshuva 494:6.

Comment: Why don't you contact Chinuch.org and ask them?

Comment: It's right there in the Yerushalmi  א"ר יוסי בי רבי בון דוד מת בעצרת

Answer (score 1):

The [date of birth and death](http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_15499_46.pdf) of Dovid Hamelech is deduced from the fact that Talmud Bavli, [Kiddushin 38a](https://daf-yomi.com/DafYomi_Page.aspx?vt=2&id=2701) says that the righteous are born and die on the same date:

> שאין ת"ל היום מה ת"ל היום מלמד שהקב"ה יושב וממלא שנותיהם של צדיקים
>   מיום ליום ומחדש לחדש שנאמר (שמות כג, כו) את מספר ימיך אמלא

See [Shaare Tshuva OC siman 494,2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9008&st=&pgnum=296&hilite=):

> שנוהגין לומר רות בשבועות. ואא"ז בבכ"ש דף רכ"א כתב הטעם לפי שדוד המלך
>   ע"ה מת בעצרת והקב"ה ממלא שנותיהם כו' ובודאי בעצרת נולד ומגילת רות
>   נכתבה ליחס דוד

Comment: But how we do know what date that was?

Comment: More importantly, there is quite a discussion in Talmud as to whether David HaMelech is a Tzaddik or not. They know for sure that he is a Ba'al Teshuvah. So the deduction is not so plain when considering Batsheva. Not everyone who is born and dies on the same day is necessarily a Tzaddik.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I skipped that part since the OP edited the question later, but  a nice answer can be found here: http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_15499_46.pdf

Comment: @YaacovDeane, it's not my deduction, I added a source indicating where it is found. Nevertheless, that's a good point but perhaps for a separate question.

Comment: @RenatoGrun First of all, Shavuah tov. I am not disagreeing with you. I was only saying that the comment only addresses the time of King David's death with certainty. In order for your answer or mine to be solid, it needs to demonstrate that King David is known and accepted to be a Tzaddik according to all opinions. Otherwise, the reasoning doesn't necessarily apply. It's only something taken on faith. And that idea, that perhaps this idea needs to be taken on faith, is a lesson unto itself.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is derived from a [gematria of a phrase from a posuk in Megillat Ruth](http://www.vorts.co.il/?p=1101). (Ruth 4:22)

> כתוב במגילת רות  "וישי הוליד את דוד"
>
> וישי הוליד את דוד = 796 .  בחג השבעות = 796.
>
> מה שמיוחד כאן שזהו הפסוק האחרון של מגילת-רות אשר קוראים אותה בחג
>   השבועות,
>
> ודוד המלך נולד ונפטר בחג-השבועות .

It's written in Megillat Ruth (4:22), "and Yishai gave birth to David."

*and Yishai gave birth to David* has a gematria of 796. *On the festival of Shavuot* also has a gematria of 796.

What is the connection here, that this last posuk of Megillat Ruth which we read on the festival of Shavuot?

King David was born and died on the festival of Shavuot.

Comment: Then why does ArtScroll cite the Yerushalmi in Chagigah if it doesn't even exist there?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah Did I say Chagigah Yerushalmi isn't a source? Looking at the halacha Artscroll cites there doesn't mention David HaMelech or Shavuot at all. Maybe they have a typo on the citation. But your question was, "Does anyone know any other source that has this information?" I gave you a quotation and link from the website וורטס in Israel. They explain the teaching comes from Megillat Ruth itself. I don't understand your down vote.

Comment: Chagigah 2:3  http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14138&hilite=2aa4e671-05c0-45a8-aeb7-e9da7f0ba9da&st=דוד+המלך&pgnum=571